# Associate a button with a specific object from an array of objects

Tags: c#, winforms, class, object, button

Using C# and Visual Studio 2017.

Basically, I'm designing a program that will allow users to reserve seats. I'm able to get it working by forcing it (more or less), but there has to be a better way.

Each button represents a seat, and when clicked - if the seat is not already reserved - the user will fill in their information and be able to reserve the seat. If the seat is already reserved, it will display the details of the person who booked the seat previously (first name, last name, etc.) - which I currently have stored in an array.

Is there a way to associate each button with an object in the array? Reserving seats is easy, but clicking on a reserved seat to show the details (or to delete a reservation and free up the seat) is the part where I think I could be a lot more efficient than what I currently have.

Ie. If seat A1 is clicked, and details are entered, the seat becomes reserved. Later, other seats are reserved. If I then want to go back and view A1 or delete the reservation, how can I associate the button A1 with the data I've stored in the array.

Comment: Don't use an array. Build a specialized class that references all the details needed, create a `LIst<SpecializedClass>` and add a `new SpecializedClass()` for each `Button` you create along with the related details. You can then filter/search the `LIst<SpecializedClass>` in any way: by Button (using its Name, Tag value, TabIndex etc.), name of a person, seat number... Anything that is referenced by a class property.

Comment: The question topic and your profile imply that this is a class assignment.  As such you probably have restrictions on the data structures you are allowed to use.  You have indicated that you are using an array of objects.  If you can only use arrays, you should state that in your question so that we do not waste time making irrelevant recommendations.

Comment: You could use the `Tag` property of the buttons. But I would not store anything in an array. Why not store the `seat ID` in the tag of the button, and when clicked fetch the info you need from your database using the `Seat ID` from the tag ?

Comment: @TnTinMn It is an assignment, but we don't have any restrictions on what we are allowed to use, if there were any such restrictions (like you said) I would have mentioned them. The focus is on the UI design, but obviously I would like the code to be as functional as possible from a "good design" perspective as well.

Comment: @Jimi Could you elaborate a little more on how I would implement this? All the buttons have a `Tag value`, and I have created a class with the seat details (I originally was storing these in arrays, but the list sounds much better).

This question may seem silly, but when do I create a `new SpecializedClass()`? Would I initialize one for each button/seat at the beginning of my program?

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a solution that I've used, thanks to the comment above (Jimi) for the `List` suggestion.

The below example shows the code for displaying details from a reserved seat. The `strings` "firstName", "lastName" etc. are then put into another textbox for display. All seats are organized into a `List`, filled with class objects type "seat" where they have all the properties you can see in the code.

When a button is clicked, it fills the `txtSeatSelected` textbox which is then used to match with the appropriate seat based on the seatID string.

```
foreach (var seat in seatsList)
        {
            if (seat.seatID == txtSeatSelected.Text)
            {
                firstName = seat.firstName;
                lastName = seat.lastName;
                address = seat.address;
                city = seat.city;
                province = seat.province;
                postalCode = seat.postalCode;
            }
        }
```

Similar iterations of this code were used throughout the program to find the object I was looking to modify throughout the program depending on the situation.

Thank you for the help from the people who left comments.